# JPA. Вернуть null вместо Hibernate LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

У меня есть две таблицы-сущности с отнощением one-to-many. Использую Jpa для работы с этим и Spring JpaRepository. В некоторых случаях мне нужно считывать объект из БД с вложенным объектом, а в некоторых случаях это делать не нужно.

Принудительное считывание я сделал с помощью аннотации @NamedEntityGraph. Это работает. Но проблема в том, что когда мне нужно игнорировать, т.е. не считывать вложенный объект, при обращении к полю вылетает LazyInitializationException. Как сделать так, чтобы вместо исключения поле было просто null?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Owner.books",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("books"))
public class Owner implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "owner_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "owner_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Book> books= new HashSet<>(0);

    public Worker() {
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Book.owner",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("owner"))
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Owner owner;

    public Task() {
    }
}
```

репозиторий:

```
public interface BookRepository  extends JpaRepository<Book,Long>{

@Query("select t from Book t")
@EntityGraph(value = "Book.owner", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Book> findAllWithOwner();

@Query("select t from Book t where t.id = :aLong")
@EntityGraph(value = "Book.owner", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
Book findOneWithOwner(Long aLong);
```

}

Как видно эти кастомные методы в репозитории возвращают принудительно все включаемые объекты. А когда я делаю вызов метода например repository#findAll() то он не выделяет вложенные объекты - так и надо, НО при обращении к полям вылетает LazyException, а мне надо чтобы эти поля были null

Comment: попробовали `try {} catch(LazyInitializationException e){}` ?

Comment: да ну? вы серьёзно?

Comment: так как кода не вижу, только это могу предложить. А так такая же ситуация (только с кодами) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115639/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-using-spring-crudrepository

Comment: @arg а где возникает эта ошибка в коде, при сериализации или в другом месте, можете указать?